# lein test (:numbers) example

Tags: clojure, leiningen

From

```
 lein help  test
```

,,

```
(deftest ^:integration network-heavy-test
   (is (= [1 2 3] (:numbers (network-operation)))))
```

What is

```
  (:numbers (network-operation)
```

doing here?

I added the network-operation function and understand **network-heavy-test2** (and it as expected passes.

I assume that **(:numbers ..)**  or **:numbers** needs to be added / defined / called somewhere?

**network-heavy-test** fails with

```
FAIL in (network-heavy-test1) (core_test.clj:23)
expected: (= [1 2 3] (:numbers (network-operation)))
actual: (not (= [1 2 3] nil))
```

....

```
(defn network-operation [] [1 2 3])

(deftest ^:integration network-heavy-test2
  (is (= [1 2 3] (network-operation))))

(deftest ^:integration network-heavy-test
   (is (= [1 2 3] (:numbers (network-operation)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

`:numbers`, when called as a function, looks up the key `:numbers` in a map. So, network-operation must return a map:

```
(defn network-operation []
  {:numbers [1 2 3] :extras "whatever"})
```

Comment: Ok thx. Is :numbers a clojure "built in" keyword?, or is just a "generic"(user created) keyword, (that acts like any other keyword) ?

Comment: And if :numbers IS a "builtin" where is it documented? I've looked all through the Clojure docs and haven't found it

Comment: It's just a keyword like any other. Not a special case of any kind.

Comment: Ok, I get it, ':numbers' was defined in network-operation, so it's NOT a "built-in".

Comment: In Clojure, there is no such thing as a "built in keyword" per se - keywords in Clojure are tokens that stand for themselves.